# Keras - Three similar models created but only one is learning

Tags: keras

I created three Convolutional Autoencoders with the same architecture to extract features from some images related to different types of trees.

My code is something like:

```
model1 = myAutoencoder()
model2 = myAutoencoder()
model3 = myAutoencoder()

opt = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001)
loss = keras.losses.MeanSquaredError()

model1.compile(opt=opt, loss=loss)
model2.compile(opt=opt, loss=loss)
model3.compile(opt=opt, loss=loss)
```

Then I train:

```
#X1, X2, X3 are tensors of 64x64 RGB images: for example(100, 64,64,3)
model1.fit(X1, X1)  
model2.fit(X2, X2) 
model3.fit(X3, X3)
```

However, only the first model is learning, while the second and third are stuck with the same loss as in the figure:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8FlXW.png)

Interestingly, if I swap the positions of let's say model1 and model2, like this:

```
model2.fit(X2, X2)  
model1.fit(X1, X1) 
model3.fit(X3, X3)
```

then only model 2 is learning and models 1 and 3 are stuck. I cannot figure out why...

**edit:** The actual training that I am doing is this:

```
def scheduler(epoch, lr):
if epoch < 50:
    return lr
else:
    return lr * np.math.exp(-0.1)


model2.fit(X2, X2, epochs=100, callbacks=[LearningRateScheduler(scheduler)])  
model1.fit(X1, X1, epochs=100, callbacks=[LearningRateScheduler(scheduler)]) 
model3.fit(X3, X3, epochs=100, callbacks=[LearningRateScheduler(scheduler)])
```

I figured out that if I delete the callbacks the learning process is "normal", is there a reason why the callbacks are interfering between models?

Comment: use a different LearningRateScheduler instance for each model